# How to introduce a new topic in conversation (like "by the way", "speaking of")?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, spoken-language, conversational

In English we can use "by the way" to introduce a topic that not related to the previous one. Or we can use "speaking of"/"apropos" when we are using a theme just mentioned to introduce a related topic.

I'm basically looking for Latin's equivalents to those two cases. I've seen **obiter** means "by the way", yet I'm not sure this can be used in the conversational-transition sense I'm seeking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suggestion for this purpose is ***ceterum***.
See [part II.A in the L&S entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DC%3Aentry+group%3D35%3Aentry%3Dceterus) for the use of this adverb to introduce something new.

The entry in L&S comes with attestations in classical literature.
For another kind of example, consider perhaps the most famous unattested phrase of classical Latin:

> Ceterum censeo Carthaginem esse delendam.

There are different variants out there, as Cato's saying has not been preserved in writing.
It is mentioned in texts but never as a direct quote.

Answer (score 0):

There is "non solum...sed etiam" = "not only...but also", in a conversational gambit.

Thanks to Joonas and a supplement to his answer, Cato might have said--

non solum molestia sed etiam carthaginem esse delendam.

"Not only a nuisance but also Carthage must be destroyed".

(There is a full grammatical analysis of Cato's declaration on Wiki: "Carthago delenda est".)

Comment: How would you use that phrase to introduce a new topic?  I take *ceterum* to be something similar in this context to the colloquial English "and, changing the subject,..."  I don't see how *non solum* works that way at all.

Comment: @C Monsour: Not only "that" but also "something tenuously, or otherwise, connected with it". What's the problem?

Comment: I think you could interpret what @CMonsour is saying so that it's the *sed etiam* that introduces the new thing. And that new thing ought to be related to the previous one. The whole pair *non solum ... sed etiam* is used to add one thing to another, whereas the OP was after moving to a new topic altogether. I agree that that's a problem with this suggestion. A good phrase, but not quite for this use.

Comment: @tony In your quotation, Cato isn't changing the topic at *sed etiam* but at *non solum*.  (He would say this whatever the topic had been.)  Obviously, *non solum* sets up a contrast with whatever comes after *sed etiam*.  It isn't related to the fact that Cato is changing the topic.  He just is, without a segway, which was sort of his style.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Understood.

Comment: @C Monsour: It was what Cato "might" have said; a supplement to Joonas's answer. Anyway, I can see that I got this one wrong.